# How can I use LESS in jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, css, less

I'm new with jsfiddle, and I trying to use LESS but I did not see it in the language options, how can I make it work with LESS.

I try to link less.min.js in external resources but neither worked

Please help me.

**EDIT1:**

I'm proving some features of less and that I want is compile my LESS just on jsfiddle to see the result right there

Comment: Use http://jsbin.com instead, they have it out of the box

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jsFiddle does not directly support `less`, so <kbd>fork</kbd> this

http://jsfiddle.net/T2Xe9/

that @aaronlayton has created and you should be good to go.

Comment: The link suggested is broken.

Comment: @Shiva the link is broken

Comment: Just fixed it. Sorry about that.